# Evaluate a Word Wildcard Without Using a Find Object In VSTO Plugin

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word, vsto, wildcard

My original problem was to be able to search using a wildcard for text inside the "bullet" of a list, such as:

```
1.1 - Text here
```

Where the wildcard might be `[0-9].[0-9]`, and the item `Text here` could be found.

Since it doesn't appear to be possible to search the values of the indices of the list using the Find object, I was thinking I'd just manually iterate over values of the labels (`ListFormat.ListString`) and see if they match the wildcard.. But I can't figure out a way to check if a string (not in the document, mind you!) matches a wildcard.

My plan if this isn't possible was to manually convert the user-provided Word wildcard into a regex and then use that to compare the list indices, but I would rather be able to use wildcards directly. I found [a blog post about converting a wildcard to a regex](http://dpotter.net/technical/2007/09/converting-wildcard-to-regular-expression/) where he links [this solution on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes), but that solution seems to be about non-word related. It does appear to be doing basically what I'm doing, which is replacing characters in the wildcard with their equivalents for a regex.

Here is the kind of thing I mean. (I had clicked inside the numbering, which is why they're highlighted)

[image]

If you try to search "1.1.1" in this document, it will not return any results, since the value is inside the list numbering. My objective is to be able to determine whether any given list numbering matches a user-provided wildcard expression.

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the document? More specifically, where the numbers you're interested "live"? Are they "native" to a specific style, for example? Or could they just be anywhere?

Comment: @CindyMeister I added an image to explain what list numbers I'm talking about. They could be inserted by manually selecting a list numbering, or they could just type "1.1.1 Text", press enter and have word automatically make it into a list

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a particularly reliable solution, but this may be the best I can do if there is no way to use Word's actual wildcard parser. I would still be very interested in a better solution!

Finding which paragraphs in a range have a list identifier which matches the Word wildcard:

```
var regex = WildcardConverter.ToRegex(wildcardPattern);
foreach (Paragraph para in range.ListParagraphs)
{
    var identifier = para.Range.ListFormat.ListString;
    bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(identifier, regex);
}
```

Converting to regex:

```
public static class WildcardConverter
{
    public static string ToRegex(string wildcard)
    {
        return wildcard
            .Replace("+", @"\+")
            .Replace("|", @"\|")
            .Replace("^", @"\^")
            .Replace("$", @"\$")
            .Replace(".", @"\.")
            .Replace("#", @"\#")
            .ReplaceRegex(Unescaped("?"), ".")
            .ReplaceRegex(Unescaped("*"), ".*")
            .ReplaceRegex(Unescaped("[") + Unescaped("!"), "[^")
            .ReplaceRegex(Unescaped("@"), "+")
            .ReplaceRegex(Unescaped("<"), "(^|\b)")
            .ReplaceRegex(Unescaped(">"), "($|\b)")
            ;
    }

    private static string Unescaped(string value)
    {
        return @"(?<!\\)" + Regex.Escape(value);
    }
}
```

Where ReplaceRegex is just an extension method doing what you'd expect:

```
public static string ReplaceRegex(this string str, string pattern, string replacement)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replacement);
}
```